# scp not working when my ssh is working perfectly

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-agent

I am having issues in scp a file to another user:

```
scp filename USERNAME@192.168.0.1:~/path/to/directory
```

I only get the below line, but scp doesn't happen:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-KjEHW3vNQqjE/agent.8177; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Ensure that any dotfiles sourced on `ssh` login to not produce extraneous output or user prompts, _e.g._ `.bashrc`

Comment: there is nothing in my .bashrc that is prompting this.

Comment: what is `type scp`? What is the other USERNAME `.bashrc`?